# Is there a DRY way to reuse a forloop?

Tags: dry

Say I have a slightly complicated for loop, being used in different situations. Is there a way to extract that forloop and still keep the code readable?

For example:

```
private function bar(){
    for(i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++){
       if(arrayA[i].someVar == foobar){
         doSomethingA();
       }
    }
}
private function foo(){
    for(i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++){
       if(arrayA[i].someVar == foobar){
         doSomethingB();
       }
    }
}
```

The way I would do this/answer the question is to write something like this:

```
private function loopFunction(callback:Function){
        for(i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++){
           if(arrayA[i].someVar == foobar){
             callback();
           }
        }
    }
  private function bar(){
       loopFunction(doSomethingA);
  }
  private function foo(){
       loopFunction(doSomethingB);
   }
```

However I find this approach makes the code rather unreadable at times, as you aren't quite sure who is doing what when. Especially if the function passed in comes from another class. Is there a better way to do this?

Another reason why this sollution may not work is if you need to pass in different parameters to the callback function.  For example.

```
private function bar(){
        for(i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++){
           if(arrayA[i].someVar == foobar){
             doSomethingA(arrayA);
           }
        }
    }
    private function foo(){
        for(i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++){
           if(arrayA[i].someVar == foobar){
             doSomethingB(i);
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Depending on the language `filter` or `map` might be the more readable approach and hides the loop from you.

Comment: @Sirko you mean like arrayA.filter(doSomethingA) and arrayA.filter(doSomethingB)  ?

Comment: +1 Good question IMO. I'd personally (for what that's worth!) use callbacks too if the loop was complex enough to avoid re-writing. Re "_as you aren't quite sure who is doing what when_", isn't that the point of nice generic code like this?

Comment: You can get around the issue of different callback signatures (in some languages, at least) by using a parameter of the base class (eg `Object` in C#).  If there's more than one parameter required, then the `Object` passed could be eg a `Dictionary` or your own custom `ParameterObject` of parameters.  But yes... this is at the detriment of readability.

Comment: Well that was answered more quickly then I thought it would be :)
I'll wait for a few upvotes before deciding which answer is more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) such as `map`, `fold`, and `filter` provide this kind of functionality. Of course, the precise implementation will vary by language.

Here's a sample in C#:

```
var foobarList = arrayA.Where(x => x.someVar == foobar).ToList();
foobarList.ForEach(x => doSomethingA());
foobarList.ForEach(x => doSomethingB());
```

And VB.NET:

```
Dim foobarList = arrayA.Where(Function(x) x.someVar = foobar).ToList()
foobarList.ForEach(Function(x) doSomethingA())
foobarList.ForEach(Function(x) doSomethingB())
```

And Javascript:

```
var foobarList = arrayA.filter(function(x) { return x.someVar == foobar });
foobarList.forEach(function(x) { doSomethingA(); });
foobarList.forEach(function(x) { doSomethingB(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stop abstracting when it is making your code worse :)

Many languages have higher level constructs built in to deal with common iteration patterns. C++11 has range-based for loops to make iterating over data structures less tedious. Functional languages often have `map`, `fold` and `filter`.